# PowerShell: read lines from text file, construct source and destination file names, then copy files

Tags: powershell

I'm a [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) novice, and I'd love to be able to script this.  I have a text file where each line is part of a file name without the path or extension.  I'd like a one-liner that loops through each line of the file (with a gc - [Get-Content](http://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html), right?), takes the content of the line, constructs the source path (the network drive and extension are static), constructs a destination path, and then copies each file.  My file content is like this:

```
12345678
98765432
32145698
12365782
```

And my source folder is a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path like this:

```
\\server\share
```

And my destination folder is:

```
c:\temp\files
```

I would like to do the equivalent of this DOS command, using `$_` as the text from each line of the file:

```
copy \\server\share\$_.ext c:\temp\files\$_.ext
```

I'm pretty sure I can use `gc` and `$_` to access each line of the file, and that I need to use `cp` to copy the files, but I'm having trouble constructing the source and destination file names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
gc theFileName | 
  %{ "{0}.ext" -f $_ } |
  %{ copy "\\server\share\$_" "c:\temp\files\$_" }
```

It can actually be done on one line but it looks better formmated as multiple lines for this answer :)

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks very much!  @JaredPar, my personal Powershell coach.

Comment: anything wrong with `gc theFileName | %{ cp '\\server\share\$_.ext' 'C:\temp\files' }`? Or would that betoo short? :-)

Comment: @Johannes, I *think* that will work but I forget the parsing rules on replacement within a string occasionally and wasn't sure if the .ext would be interpretd correctly.  Hence went the safe route

Comment: Johannes, watch out for the single quotes.  Those won't expand $_.

Answer (score 5):

Copy-Item can take a script block directly in this case so the Foreach-Object stages are unnecessary:

```
gc theFileName | cpi -l {"\\server\share\$_.exe"} c:\temp\files -whatif
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter once you're satisfied it works. The -l is short for -LiteralPath which helps PowerShell determine which parameterset is in use.  Also better to use literal path here so that wildcard characters don't get globbed (unless you want that - if so then use -path).

Essentially pipeline bound parameters can be specified via scriptblocks and PowerShell will attempt to resolve the result of the scriptblock to the type expected by the pipeline bound parameter.

Comment: Is this true in general or a nifty feature of Copy-Item?

Comment: This works for any parameter that is also pipeline bound.  The PowerShell parameter parser/binder will eval the script block for pipeline bound parameters unless, of course, the parameter type is [scriptblock].

Comment: Indeed, it even works on ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName params -- awesome!

Comment: Nope, nevermind, not as cool as I expected.  Your syntax does not *transform* the property that's attached to the pipeline object -- it *overwrites* it.  Still handy for one-off cases but far less useful in general.