# Can’t copy folder content from one server to list of servers

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a folder full of exe and msi files from one server to all servers in the list in a text file.

So far I was lucky to copy or create a empty folder in the destination servers but no luck in copying the content of the folder on the source server. Can some one help me achieve this?

```
$comname = Get-Content -path 'H:\Installation Files\Patch Update files\server.txt'
Foreach ($value in $comname) {
    $ss = "H:\Installation Files\Patch Update Files\Jun 2018"
    If (Test-path $ss) {
        $dest = "\\$value\H$\Install.*\Patch.*\Jun 2018"
        If (Test-path $dest) {
            Copy-Item -path $ss -destination $dest -force
        }
        Else {
            Write-output "$dest does not exists"
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-output "$ss does not exists"
    }
}
```

Can someone help in copying all the contents/Files in the source server folder to destination server folder.
I am not getting any error. The script runs fine and copies or create an empty folder on the destination server. How to get the contents/Files in the source server folder to copied to the destination server?

Comment: Your `$dest` is invalid. Folder names can not contain wildcards.

Comment: @KenWhite The problem is there are folders named “Install Files” or “Installation Files” or “InstallationFiles” and such on different server. So how to copy them to the existing folder?

Comment: You have to specify the folder. You can't use wildcard expansion in directory names, especially at multiple levels. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1903076 has some suggestions about how to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite tried the correct folder destination for one server and it still creates the empty folder rather than copying the content of the source folder. How to fix that?

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix that, because I can't see the code you tried. (I tried, but the letters on your screen were fuzzy from where I'm sitting, and I couldn't quite make them out.)

Comment: @KenWhite I used $dest = “\\$value\h$\Installation Files\Patch Update Files\Jun 2018”

Comment: @KenWhite this created a folder Jun 2018 under the folder Jun 2018 that already exist on the server and it’s empty.

Comment: From a PowerShell prompt, type `help Copy-Item -examples`, and look at examples 2 and 3.

Comment: @KenWhite the -Recurse worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Will add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can’t use regex on Destination folder path.
And use of -Recurse solved the problem of copying all the files in the folder after creating a destination folder.

```
Else {
   New-Item -path $dest -type directory -force
   Copy-Item -path $source -destination $dest -Recurse
}
```