# Powershell to Install all exe and msu in a folder on remote server

Tags: powershell

I was able to copy all the Patch and exe from one server to list of server with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915482/7115396)
Now I am trying to install all the patch and exe on the destination folder on the remote server remotely.
Using

```
$comname = Get-Content -Path ‘H:\InstallationFiles\server.txt’
$fname = Get-ChildItem ‘H:\InstallationFiles\Patch’ -Recurse -force | select-object FullName
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts * -Force
Foreach($sname in $comname){
    Foreach($installpath in $fname){
         $newproc=([WMICLASS]”\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).Create(“$installpath /s”)
          If($newproc.ReturnValue -eq 0){
              Write-Host $_ $newproc.ProcessID
          }
           Else {
               Write-Host $_ Process Create failed with $newproc.ReturnValue
           }
      }
}
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Process Create failed with
Cannot convert value “\\\root\cimv2:win32_Process” to type “System.Management.ManagementClass”. Error: “Invalid parameter “
At H:/InstallationFiles/installfiletoserver.ps1:15 char:9
+            $newproc=([WMICLASS]”\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).Create(“$installFil ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [], Runtime.Exception
          + FullyQualfiedErrorId : InvalidCastToWMIClass
```

Even I tried using Invoke-command but that fails as well.

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName $sname -ScriptBlock {
       Start-Process $installpath -ArgumentList ‘/silent’ -wait
}
```

The Invoke-command fails with

```
[servername] Connection to remote server servername  failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request because the server name cannot be resolved l. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (servername:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComputerNotFound, PSSessionStateBroken
```

I get this error for all the servers and even to run other commands like new-item etc on the servers with script block on Invoke-Command.
I am not sure what i am missing. Can someone help me install all the exe and msu on a folder on remote server remotely with Powershell?
Thank you!

Comment: `$_` is a special value that is only sometimes available in your case I believe that you want `$sname`

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks for the response. Now the error is gone but I get return code 9 “Process Create failed with 9” for all the servers.

Comment: Error code 9 is a Path not found Error.

Comment: @EBGreen yeah, was able to find the issue, it’s “select-object FullName” it’s returning “@{FullName=H:/InstallationFiles/Patch/filename.exe}” any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: @EBGreen -ExpandProperty fixed the link but still I am getting pathnotfound error code 9. ☹️

Comment: Well then you are going to need to sort out that path issue. My first guess would be that the H: drive is not available in the process environment that you are launching.

Comment: @EBGreen Thank you so much, there is a typo in the destination folder on server, was able to fix and run the code to install exe, but can’t run msu. May i know if WMIClass can run msu?

Comment: try running wusa.exe and giving it the msu as a parameter.

Comment: @EBGreen I have never seen Wusa.exe before, and not sure how to implement it. Not sure how to google it, google hits are not so helpful. Can you let me know an example or sample or link to how to use wusa.exe in powershell?

Comment: google `wusa.exe install msu` and the first hit is [How to install a .msu update on Windows 7 from the command line.](https://kb.cscc.edu/article/how-to-install-a-msu-update-on-windows-7-from-the-command-line-63.html)

Comment: @EBGreen I tried “Invoke-command -ComputerName $sname -ScriptBlock { wusa.exe $installpath /quiet /norestart }” but it failed with the same error I got for Invoke-command in the question. Can you help fix it?

Comment: Use WMI like you did for the other executables.

Answer (score 0):

Is the MSU file that you are trying to install? if yes, you need to decompress the file.. will generate the cab file I guess... and than you can make it.

```
$newproc=([WMICLASS]”\\$_\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).Create(“DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:$installpath ”)
```

Comment: I tried this answer, it ran successfully but the msu was not installed on the server. Can you please help fix it?

Comment: Hum!! My bad man, where you find "...\\$_\root\cimv2...." switch to "...\\$sname\root\cimv2..."

Comment: I was trying \\$sname\root... the whole time and I still see process ID generated for each exe and msu but on the destination server the msu were not installed.

Comment: 1st you need to decompress the msu file... 2nd gonna generate CAB file... 3rd use this cab file

Comment: yeah, I am extracting and running the cab, but nothing works, but when I try it on the destination server directly it works! “$newproc=([WMICLASS]”\\$sname\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).create(“wusa.exe $installpath /extract:$destpath “)” then “$newproc1=([WMICLASS])”\\$sname\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).create(“DISM.exe /online /Add-package /packagepath:$destpath “)”

Comment: I'm afraid that $destpath is not $destpath + filename.cab... did you already try write-host $destpath? What shown? Shown the file name.cab or just the path?

Comment: yeah $destpath is filepath+filename.msu and not .cab

Comment: Hum... now i understand why not installing... hey not in the code to run cab files...

Comment: Check I'd Dism still running in the process... If don't see of the updates need to restart the server... after that check if the update was installed

Comment: I see WUSA.exe still running in the destination server. Awaiting for it to complete.

Comment: it's still running?

Comment: I ended every process and restarted the server and tried again once for one msu and it’s still running for more than 30mins!

Answer (score 0):

```
$comname = Get-Content -Path ‘H:\InstallationFiles\server.txt’
```

$fname = Get-ChildItem ‘H:\InstallationFiles\Patch’ -Recurse -force | select-object FullName
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts * -Force
Foreach($sname in $comname){
    Foreach($installpath in $fname){
         $newproc=([WMICLASS]”\$sname\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).create(“wusa.exe $installpath /extract:$destpath“)
          If($newproc.ReturnValue -eq 0){
              Write-Host $_ $newproc.ProcessID
          }
           Else {
               Write-Host $_ Process Create failed with $newproc.ReturnValue
           }
      }
}

$fname = Get-ChildItem ‘H:\InstallationFiles\Patch*.cab’ -Recurse -force | select-object FullName
Foreach($sname in $comname){
    Foreach($installpath in $fname){
         $newproc=([WMICLASS]”\$sname\root\cimv2:win32_Process”).create(“DISM.exe /online /Add-package /packagepath:$destpath“)
          If($newproc.ReturnValue -eq 0){
              Write-Host $_ $newproc.ProcessID
          }
           Else {
               Write-Host $_ Process Create failed with $newproc.ReturnValue
           }
      }
}

Try this.. But I think that we gonna add a wait on wusa.exe and dism.exe.. to wait to close it..

so try it with only one file.. for the start...

Comment: I just get the return code printed on the screen, but neither I see the msu extracted to a cab file on the destination server nor the patch installed. ☹️

Comment: $newproc1=([WMICLASS]”\\$sname\root\cimv2:win32_process”).create(“DISM.exe /online /Add-package /Packagepath:$destinpath”)

Comment: $newproc=([WMICLASS]”\\$sname\root\cimvs:win32_process”).create(“wusa.exe $installpath /extract:$destinpath”)

Comment: I just get the process ID printed in the screen! No return codes!

Comment: hey... where you find dism.exe... on your code switch to this... dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:$destinpath /ignorecheck /quiet /norestart in this code above....

Comment: Hi, I was busy with something else, did not happen to check this, now I changed few WMICLASS to Invoke-command as the issue was with server proxy. Fixed that and Invoke-command runs fine. I tried your answer as “invoke-command -computername $sname -credential $creds -scriptblock { start-process -filepath ‘Wusa.exe’ -argumentlist “$installpath /extract:$destinpath /silent” -wait -passthru } -jobname “job1” -asjob “ then “wait-job -name job1” this keeps running forever. On the destination server I can see wusa.exe running but the msu was never extracted. It did not move to ‘dism.exe’